# jump into file line c#

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

how can i jump into some line in my file, e.g line 300 in c:\text.txt?

Comment: @aharont, a file is just a sequence of bytes stored on a hard drive. You need to specify what does a *line* means in your case. For example  on Linux based systems new line represented by the `\n` character while on Windows it is the sequence `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim arrText() As String 
Dim lineThreeHundred As String

arrText = File.ReadAllLines("c:\test.txt") 

lineThreeHundred = arrText(299)
```

Edit: C# Version

```
string[] arrText;
string lineThreeHundred;

arrText = File.ReadAllLines("c:\test.txt");
lineThreeHundred = arrText[299];
```

Answer (score 13):

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        reader.ReadLine();
    }
    // Now you are at line 300. You may continue reading
}
```

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov: "Now you are at line 300. You may continue reading." Be careful if there are less than 300 lines!

Comment: @Jason, I intentionally omitted exception handling to demonstrate the process of *jumping to a line* in a file. The original question was not how to write production ready code that I can copy-paste that will jump to a line in a file. There are many other things that we must take care of such as verify file existence, verify that the account our process executes under has read permissions on the file, log errors, etc...

Comment: Whoa, it's a big leap from pointing out that your comment is slightly misleading to interpreting my comment as if I'm saying that is not safe for use in production.

Answer (score 9):

Line-delimited files are not designed for random access. Thus, you have to seek through the file by reading and discarding the necessary number of lines.

Modern approach:

```
class LineReader : IEnumerable<string>, IDisposable {
        TextReader _reader;
        public LineReader(TextReader reader) {
            _reader = reader;
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator() {
            string line;
            while ((line = _reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                yield return line;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            _reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
// path is string
int skip = 300;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
using (var lineReader = new LineReader(sr)) {
    IEnumerable<string> lines = lineReader.Skip(skip);
    foreach (string line in lines) {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Simple approach:

```
string path;
int count = 0;
int skip = 300;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) {
     while ((count < skip) && (sr.ReadLine() != null)) {
         count++;
     }
     if(!sr.EndOfStream)
         Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things I noticed:

1. Microsoft's [sample usage of the
   StreamReader constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy.aspx) checks
   whether the file exists first.
2. You ought to notify the user, via an
   message on screen or in a log, if
   the file either doesn't exist or is
   shorter than we expected.  This lets
   you know about any unexpected
   errors, if they happen while you are
   debugging other parts of the system.
   I realize this wasn't part of your
   original question, but it's a good
   practice.

So this is a combination of several of the other answers.

```
string path = @"C:\test.txt";
int count = 0;

if(File.Exists(path))
{
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"c:\test.txt"))
  {
    while (count < 300 && reader.ReadLine() != null)
    {
      count++;
    }

    if(count != 300)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("There are less than 300 lines in this file.");
    }
    else
    {
      // keep processing
    }
  }
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine("File '" + path + "' does not exist.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the specified line from a text file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="lineNumber">The number of the line to return.</param>
/// <param name="path">Identifies the text file that is to be read.</param>
/// <returns>The specified line, is it exists, or an empty string otherwise.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">The line number is negative, or the path is missing.</exception>
/// <exception cref="System.IO.IOException">The file could not be read.</exception>
public static string GetNthLineFromTextFile(int lineNumber, string path)
{
    if (lineNumber < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Invalid line number \"{0}\". Must be greater than zero.", lineNumber));
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        throw new ArgumentException("No path was specified.");

    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(path))
    {
        for (int currentLineNumber = 0; currentLineNumber < lineNumber; currentLineNumber++)
        {
            if (reader.EndOfStream)
                return string.Empty;
            reader.ReadLine();
        }
        return reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```