# file handling in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net

There is a list of things I want to do. I have a forms application.

1. Go to a particular line. I know how to go in a serial manner, but is there any way by which I can jump to a particular line no.
2. To find out total no of line.

Comment: Did you try FileStream class?

Comment: There is no way to access a specific line number in a file without iterating, or to get the number of lines (though it could be hidden to the developer if that's what you wish). If you can change the file format, you may want to add a header or a footer with an index that tells the offset of each line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the file is not too big, you can try the [ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx).

This reads the whole file, into a string array, where every line is an element of the array.

Example:

```
var fileName = @"C:\MyFolder\MyFileName.txt";
var contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Line: 10: " + contents[9]);
Console.WriteLine("Number of lines:");
Console.WriteLine(contents.Lenght);
```

But be aware: **This reads in the whole file into memory.**

If the file is too big:

Open the file ([OpenText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)), and create a Dictionary to store the offset of every line. Scan every line, and store the offset. Now you can go to every line, and you have the number of lines.

```
var lineOffset = new Dictionary<int, long>();
using (var rdr = System.IO.File.OpenText(fileName)) {
   int lineNr = 0;
   lineOffset.Add(0,0);
   while (rdr.ReadLine() != null)) {
       lineNr++;
       lineOffset.Add(lineNr, rdr.BaseStream.Position);
   }

   // Goto line 10
   rdr.BaseStream.Position = lineOffset[10];
   var line10 = rdr.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: there's an error that is displayed wen i run this code.  Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,int>.Add(int, int)' has some invalid arguments .

Comment: I see, that's because the Position is a long. I changed the code. What's the size of your file?

Comment: Unless you have hundreds of them, I suggest to use the ReadAllLines(). It's more simple.

Comment: It depends on the specifications of your target machine, how fast you need this data, what's the importance of the data in the app, and how long you need to keep the data in memory (milliseconds-days). But I was thinking about megabytes, on a modern computer 10 MB should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This would help for your first point: [jump into file line c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103250/jump-into-file-line-c)